# merge and quantity add javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, lodash

Hello I have the following:

```
> var gb = [{"sku": "EP01", "qty": 10, "cntry": "GB"}, {"sku": "EP02", "qty": 5, "cntry": "GB"}, {"sku": "EP03", "qty": 15, "cntry": "GB"}];
> 
> var de = [{"sku": "EP01", "qty": 100, "cntry": "DE"}, {"sku": "EP02", "qty": 25, "cntry": "DE"}];
> var obj1 = gb.concat(de);
[ { sku: 'EP01', qty: 100, cntry: 'DE' },
  { sku: 'EP02', qty: 25, cntry: 'DE' },
  { sku: 'EP03', qty: 15, cntry: 'GB' },
  { sku: 'EP01', qty: 100, cntry: 'DE' },
  { sku: 'EP02', qty: 25, cntry: 'DE' } ]
>
```

This is wrong as I get two `{ sku: 'EP01', qty: 100, cntry: 'DE' }` where as I would like to get one merged object like `{ sku: 'EP01', total: 110, qty-gb: 10, qty-de: 100 }`

My list has about 8,000 entries and in some cases one may exist in one but not the other.

What is an efficient way to achieve this on node.js with lodash?

I tried this:

```
allStockAPI = exports.allStockAPI = (req) ->
  Promise.props
    stocksAPI: stockAPI(req)
    germanStocks: germanStocks.getStocks(config.germanStocksUrl)
  .then (result) ->
    newDe = result.germanStocks.map (i) ->
      return Object.values(i)
    result.stocksAPI.forEach (i) ->
      i.pop()

    rows = result.stocksAPI.concat newDe
    #console.log rows
    skus = rows.map (row) ->
      {
        sku: row[0],
        val: row
      }
    groupedRows = _(skus).groupBy('sku').value()
    rows = _(Object.keys(groupedRows)).uniq().value().map (sku) ->
      rows = groupedRows[sku].map (row) ->
        row.val
      rows = rows.map (row) ->
        if row[row.length - 2]
          row[row.length - 2] = row[row.length - 1] + ' office : ' + row[row.length - 2]
        if row[row.length - 2] == null
          row[row.length - 2] = ''
        row

      stock = rows.reduce (prev, cur) ->
        prev[prev.length - 1] = 'UK/DE'
        if (prev[prev.length - 2])
          prev[prev.length - 2] = prev[prev.length - 2] + '<br>' + cur[prev.length - 2]
        else 
          prev[prev.length - 2] = cur[prev.length - 2]
        prev
      stock
    rows
```

but is incorrect

Comment: What lodash combos have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I don't know how to change the code below to coffreescript so I'll just answer this in javascript.

You can do the following:

1. Use [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) to group items by `sku`.
2. [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) the grouped items and return the transformed `qty` keys by country through [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) and the `total` value through [sumBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sumBy).

```js
var gb = [{"sku": "EP01", "qty": 10, "cntry": "GB"}, {"sku": "EP02", "qty": 5, "cntry": "GB"}, {"sku": "EP03", "qty": 15, "cntry": "GB"}];

var de = [{"sku": "EP01", "qty": 100, "cntry": "DE"}, {"sku": "EP02", "qty": 25, "cntry": "DE"}];

var result = _(gb)
  .concat(de)
  .groupBy('sku')
  .map(function(items) {
    return _.reduce(items, function(acc, item) {
      return _(item)
        .omit(['qty', 'cntry'])
        .set('qty-' + item.cntry, item.qty)
        .assign(acc)
        .value();
    }, { total: _.sumBy(items, 'qty') });
  })
  .value();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in plain Javascript with an object as reference to the elements of the inserted objects.

```js
var gb = [{ "sku": "EP01", "qty": 10, "cntry": "GB" }, { "sku": "EP02", "qty": 5, "cntry": "GB" }, { "sku": "EP03", "qty": 15, "cntry": "GB" }],
    de = [{ "sku": "EP01", "qty": 100, "cntry": "DE" }, { "sku": "EP02", "qty": 25, "cntry": "DE" }],
    result = function (data) {
        function update(a) {
            if (!hash[a.sku]) {
                hash[a.sku] = { sku: a.sku, total: 0 };
                r.push(hash[a.sku]);
            }
            hash[a.sku]['qty-' + a.cntry.toLowerCase()] = a.qty;
            hash[a.sku].total += a.qty;
        }

        var hash = Object.create(null),
            r = [];

        data.forEach(a => a.forEach(update));
        return r;
    }([gb, de]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Node all ES6 goodies are at your service. So i wouldn't use extra libraries like lodash or underscore. You may do like this

```js
var gb = [{"sku": "EP01", "qty": 10, "cntry": "GB"}, {"sku": "EP02", "qty": 5, "cntry": "GB"}, {"sku": "EP03", "qty": 15, "cntry": "GB"}],
    de = [{"sku": "EP01", "qty": 100, "cntry": "DE"}, {"sku": "EP02", "qty": 25, "cntry": "DE"}];
merged = (...arrs) => arrs.reduce((p,c) => c.reduce((f,s) => f.concat(s),p),[]);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(merged(gb,de),null,2) + "</pre>");
```

In case you have doubts like any duplicates might occur, it's always best to apply a filter at the end of the chain. I will also implement that one fyi.